# Android FileNotFound canread and exists false media whatsapp files

Tags: android, whatsapp, filenotfoundexception

I'm trying to read a file that exists, but I can not. Thanks!

[image]

```
File f = new File("/mnt/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20180628-WA0000.jpg");

File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
Log.w("Whatsapp","#SDDIR CANREAD? "+ sdDir.canRead() +" PATH: "+ sdDir.getAbsolutePath());

f.setReadable(true,false);
Log.w("Whatsapp","#FILE: "+ f.getName() +" l:"+ f.length() +" exists:"+ f.exists() +" canRead:"+ f.canRead() +" PATH: "+ f.getPath() +" ABSOLUTE: "+ f.getAbsolutePath());
```

LOG

```
#SDDIR CANREAD? false PATH: /storage/emulated/0
#FILE: IMG-20180628-WA0000.jpg l:0 exists:false canRead:false PATH: /mnt/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20180628-WA0000.jpg ABSOLUTE: /mnt/sdcard/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images/IMG-20180628-WA0000.jpg
```

[image]

[image]

AndroidManifest Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you do not have arbitrary read-write access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Second, most things in Android are case-sensitive. So, your `<uses-permission>` elements will not work.

Third, you cannot hold the `MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` permission, as that is not available for ordinary apps.

So you can fix your manifest by replacing your existing `<uses-permission>` elements with:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

However, you still may not have access to that particular file.

Comment: WORKS! Thank u so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Works!

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

[image]